# Subsite managed navigation - page not found

Tags: 2013, sub-site, managed-navigation

I want to use Managed Navigation to show a current navigation menu, for a subsite only. I've created a term set with friendly URLs, and the terms are showing in the nav. Problem is, I **sometimes** get "Page not found" errors when clicking the links.

I have read ([here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-recommendations-pages-friendly-urls-subwebs/)) that this may be due to the fact that the friendly URL starts with the name of the subsite's folder. However there doesn't appear to be a way to resolve this conflict, as a friendly URL of "/my-page" results in a full path of "/Subsite/my-page" when the term set is used only for the subsite. Renaming the subsite results in the friendly URL changing too.

Is there any way to get around this?